# Python subprocess.Popen "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: python, linux, memory

**Note:** This question was originally asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory) but the bounty time expired even though an acceptable answer was not actually found. I am re-asking this question including all details provided in the original question.

A python script is running a set of class functions every 60 seconds using the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module:

```
# sc is a sched.scheduler instance
sc.enter(60, 1, self.doChecks, (sc, False))
```

The script is running as a daemonised process using the code [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

A number of class methods that are called as part of doChecks use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to call system functions in order to get system statistics:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This runs fine for a period of time before the entire script crashing with the following error:

```
File "/home/admin/sd-agent/checks.py", line 436, in getProcesses
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 533, in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 835, in _get_handles
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

The output of free -m on the server once the script has crashed is:

```
$ free -m
                  total       used       free     shared     buffers    cached
Mem:                894        345        549          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:  345        549
Swap:                 0          0          0
```

The server is running CentOS 5.3. I am unable to reproduce on my own CentOS boxes nor with any other user reporting the same problem.

I have tried a number of things to debug this as suggested in the original question:

1. Logging the output of free -m before and after the Popen call. There is no significant change in memory usage i.e. memory is not gradually being used up as the script runs.
2. I added close_fds=True to the Popen call but this made no difference - the script still crashed with the same error. Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/1297785#1297785) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/1278961#1278961).
3. I checked the rlimits which showed (-1, -1) on both RLIMIT_DATA and RLIMIT_AS as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/1270442#1270442).
4. [An article](http://www.zenoss.com/community/wiki/common-error-messages-and-solutions/oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-in-popen2.py/) suggested the having no swap space might be the cause but swap is actually available on demand (according to the web host) and this was also suggested as a bogus cause [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/1270171#1270171).
5. The processes are being closed because that is the behaviour of using .communicate() as backed up by the Python source code and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/1216824#1216824).

The entire checks can be found at on [GitHub here](http://github.com/dmytton/sd-agent/blob/82f5ff9203e54d2adeee8cfed704d09e3f00e8eb/checks.py) with the getProcesses function defined from line 442. This is called by doChecks() starting at line 520.

The script was run with strace with the following output before the crash:

```
recv(4, "Total Accesses: 516662\nTotal kBy"..., 234, 0) = 234
gettimeofday({1250893252, 887805}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "2009-08-21 17:20:52,887 - checks"..., 91) = 91
gettimeofday({1250893252, 888362}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "2009-08-21 17:20:52,888 - checks"..., 74) = 74
gettimeofday({1250893252, 888897}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "2009-08-21 17:20:52,888 - checks"..., 67) = 67
gettimeofday({1250893252, 889184}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "2009-08-21 17:20:52,889 - checks"..., 81) = 81
close(4)                                = 0
gettimeofday({1250893252, 889591}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "2009-08-21 17:20:52,889 - checks"..., 63) = 63
pipe([4, 5])                            = 0
pipe([6, 7])                            = 0
fcntl64(7, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7f12708) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last"..., 35) = 35
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python24.zip/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent."..., 52) = 52
open("/home/admin/sd-agent/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python24.zip/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/daemon.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"/home/admin/sd-agent/dae"..., 60) = 60
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python24.zip/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/agent.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"/usr/bin/sd-agent/agent."..., 54) = 54
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/sched.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 8
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python2.4/sched"..., 55) = 55
fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7d28000
read(8, "\"\"\"A generally useful event sche"..., 4096) = 4054
write(2, "    ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "void = action(*argument)\n", 25) = 25
close(8)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7d28000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python24.zip/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks"..., 60) = 60
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python24.zip/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/checks.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"/usr/bin/sd-agent/checks"..., 64) = 64
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 8
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python2.4/subpr"..., 65) = 65
fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39931, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7d28000
read(8, "# subprocess - Subprocesses with"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "lso, the newlines attribute of t"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "code < 0:\n        print >>sys.st"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "alse does not exist on 2.2.0\ntry"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, " p2cread\n        # c2pread    <-"..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "errread, errwrite)\n", 19)    = 19
close(8)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7d28000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 8
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python2.4/subpr"..., 71) = 71
fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39931, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7d28000
read(8, "# subprocess - Subprocesses with"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "lso, the newlines attribute of t"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "code < 0:\n        print >>sys.st"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "alse does not exist on 2.2.0\ntry"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, " p2cread\n        # c2pread    <-"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "table(self, handle):\n           "..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, "rrno using _sys_errlist (or siml"..., 4096) = 4096
read(8, " p2cwrite = None, None\n         "..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "self.pid = os.fork()\n", 21)  = 21
close(8)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7d28000, 4096)                = 0
write(2, "OSError", 7)                  = 7
write(2, ": ", 2)                       = 2
write(2, "[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memor"..., 33) = 33
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
unlink("/var/run/sd-agent.pid")         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7e0d000, 4096)                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x589978}, {0xb89a60, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x589978}, 8) = 0
brk(0xa022000)                          = 0xa022000
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: runnig out of 'pipes' or filedescriptors or a kernel-resource related to these ?

Comment: Check `/var/log/messages`, or `dmesg` command.

Comment: There's nothing in the log relevant to this.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  I have very similar symptoms.  I have plenty of spare memory, but after adding swap  (like some of your answers suggest), the problem goes away.  Just wondered if you found anything out in the months between then and now. -- thanks!

Comment: I am running into the same problem but no resolution -- any ideas?

Comment: @user248237, you have to (in order of preference) either **(1) add more swap**, and/or **(2) relax the overcommit policy** (so that the OS lets you `fork` a large process like `python` even if very little free memory is available on the "promise" that an `exec` of a much smaller process will immediately follow the `fork`), and/or **(3) reduce your script's memory footprint** so `fork` doesn't have to as for as much memory on your behalf (chase down memory leaks and bloat, etc.), and/or **(4) [spawn a helper process, use `posix_spawn`/`vfork`, etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13329386/66516)**

Answer (score 108):

As a general rule (i.e. in vanilla kernels), `fork`/`clone` failures with `ENOMEM` [**occur specifically**](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/fork.c) because of either **an honest to God out-of-memory condition** (`dup_mm`, `dup_task_struct`, `alloc_pid`, `mpol_dup`, `mm_init` etc. croak), or because `security_vm_enough_memory_mm` failed you **while [enforcing](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/38a76013ad809beb0b52f60d365c960d035bd83c/mm/mmap.c#L91) the [overcommit policy](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting).**

Start by checking the vmsize of the process that failed to fork, at the time of the fork attempt, and then compare to the amount of free memory (physical and swap) as it relates to the overcommit policy (plug the numbers in.)

In your particular case, note that Virtuozzo has [additional checks](https://src.openvz.org/projects/OVZL/repos/linux-2.6.32-openvz/browse/kernel/sys.c#183) in [overcommit enforcement](https://src.openvz.org/projects/OVZL/repos/linux-2.6.32-openvz/commits/5198e6ea6a7c9c1a7d890f4c639007fce9290b05#mm/mmap.c).  Moreover, I'm not sure how much control you truly have, from **within** your container, over [swap and overcommit configuration](http://kb.odin.com/en/112740) (in order to influence the outcome of the enforcement.)

Now, in order to actually move forward I'd say you're **left with two options**:

- switch to a larger instance, or
- put some coding effort into **more effectively controlling your script's memory** footprint

**NOTE** that the coding effort may be all for naught if it turns out that it's not you, but some other guy collocated in a different instance on the same server as you running amock.

Memory-wise, we already know that **`subprocess.Popen` uses `fork`/`clone`** [under the hood](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py), meaning that every time you call it you're **requesting once more as much memory as Python is already eating up**, i.e. in the hundreds of additional MB, all in order to then `exec` a puny 10kB executable such as `free` or `ps`.  In the case of an unfavourable overcommit policy, you'll soon see `ENOMEM`.

Alternatives to `fork` that do not have this parent page tables etc. copy problem are [`vfork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork) and [`posix_spawn`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn).  But if you do not feel like rewriting chunks of `subprocess.Popen` in terms of `vfork`/`posix_spawn`, consider using `suprocess.Popen` only once, at the beginning of your script (when Python's memory footprint is minimal), to **spawn a shell script that then runs `free`/`ps`/`sleep` and whatever else in a loop** parallel to your script; poll the script's output or read it synchronously, possibly from a separate thread if you have other stuff to take care of asynchronously -- do your data crunching in Python but leave the forking to the subordinate process.

**HOWEVER**, in your particular case you can skip invoking `ps` and `free` altogether; that **information is readily available to you in Python directly from [`procfs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)**, whether you choose to access it yourself or via [existing libraries and/or packages](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20procfs).  If `ps` and `free` were the only utilities you were running, then you can **do away with `subprocess.Popen` completely**.

Finally, whatever you do as far as `subprocess.Popen` is concerned, if your script leaks memory you will still hit the wall eventually.  Keep an eye on it, and [check for memory leaks](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20memory%20leaks).

Comment: I found that running `gc.collect()` just before `subprocess.Popen` helps in the cases when the garbage collector hadn't run for a while.

Comment: I wrote a deamon to handle the helper script strategy:
https://github.com/SeanHayes/errand-boy/

I'm using it in production with one of my clients and our "Cannot allocate memory" troubles are gone.

Comment: I'd appreciate a simple diagnostic, e.g. following `/proc/fd/maps` to determine if overcommitted memory is in fact the issue

Answer (score 21):

Looking at the output of `free -m` it seems to me that you actually do not have swap memory available. I am not sure if in Linux the swap always will be available automatically on demand, but I was having the same problem and none of the answers here really helped me. Adding some swap memory however, fixed the problem in my case so since this might help other people facing the same problem, I post my answer on how to add a 1GB swap (on Ubuntu 12.04 but it should work similarly for other distributions.)

You can first check if there is any swap memory enabled.

```
$sudo swapon -s
```

if it is empty, it means you don't have any swap enabled. To add a 1GB swap:

```
$sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1024k
$sudo mkswap /swapfile
$sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Add the following line to the `fstab` to make the swap permanent.

```
$sudo vim /etc/fstab

     /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Source and more information can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: Did that fix the same problem or some other?

Comment: This did it for me at CentOS 6.4. Faced error while installing awstats, thanks.

Comment: Although this let me execute the Code, it didn't really address the problem, which probably lies in a library I use.

Comment: You fixed my problem. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 13):

For an easy fix, you could

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

if you're sure that your system has enough memory. See [Linux over commit heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688824/linux-over-commit-heuristic).

Comment: Thank you so much!
Such an easy solution, you saved my day )

Comment: maybe you know how to fix it on windows ? thanks

Comment: @warfish: has not yet happened on windows for me

Answer (score 9):

swap may not be the red herring previously suggested.  How big is the python process in question just before the `ENOMEM`?

Under kernel 2.6, `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` controls how aggressively the kernel will turn to swap, and `overcommit*` files how much and how precisely the kernel may apportion memory with a wink and a nod.  Like your facebook relationship status, [it's complicated](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt).

> *...but swap is actually available on demand (according to the web host)...*

but not according to the output of your `free(1)` command, which shows no swap space recognized by your server instance.  Now, your web host may certainly know much more than I about this topic, but virtual RHEL/CentOS systems I've used have reported swap available to the guest OS.

Adapting [Red Hat KB Article 15252](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> A Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 system
>   will run just fine with no swap space
>   at all as long as the sum of anonymous
>   memory and system V shared memory is
>   less than about 3/4 the amount of RAM.
>   .... Systems with 4GB of ram or less
>   *[are recommended to have]* a minimum of
>   2GB of swap space.

Compare your `/proc/sys/vm` settings to a plain CentOS 5.3 installation.  Add a swap file.  Ratchet down `swappiness` and see if you live any longer.

Comment: What's the best way to check the size of the python process? ps?

Comment: something like `ps -o user,pid,vsz="Mem(Kb)" -o cmd $PYTHON_PID`, or top(1), should do it.

Answer (score 5):

I continue to suspect that your customer/user has some kernel module or driver loaded which
is interfering with the `clone()` system call (perhaps some obscure security enhancement,
something like LIDS but more obscure?) or is somehow filling up some of the kernel data
structures that are necessary for `fork()`/`clone()` to operate (process table, page
tables, file descriptor tables, etc).

Here's the relevant portion of the `fork(2)` man page:

```
ERRORS
       EAGAIN fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and allocate a task  structure  for  the
              child.

       EAGAIN It  was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit was encountered.  To
              exceed this limit, the process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.

       ENOMEM fork() failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures because memory is tight.
```

I suggest having the user try this after booting into a stock, generic kernel and with only a minimal set of modules and drivers loaded (minimum necessary to run your application/script).  From there, assuming it works in that configuration, they can perform a binary search between that and the configuration which exhibits the issue.  This is standard sysadmin troubleshooting 101.

The relevant line in your `strace` is:

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7f12708) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

... I know others have talked about swap and memory availability (and I would recommend that you set up at least a small swap partition, ironically even if it's on a RAM disk ... the code paths through the Linux kernel when it has even a tiny bit of swap available have been exercised far more extensively than those (exception handling paths) in which there is zero swap available.

However I suspect that this is still a red herring.

The fact that `free` is reporting 0 (ZERO) memory in use by the cache and buffers is very disturbing.  I suspect that the `free` output ... and possibly your application issue here, are caused by some proprietary kernel module which is interfering with the memory allocation in some way.

According to the man pages for fork()/clone() the fork() system call should return EAGAIN if your call would cause a resource limit violation (RLIMIT_NPROC) ... however, it doesn't say if EAGAIN is to be returned by other RLIMIT* violations.  In any event if your target/host has some sort of weird Vormetric or other security settings (or even if your process is running under some weird SELinux policy) then it might be causing this -ENOMEM failure.

It's pretty unlikely to be a normal run-of-the-mill Linux/UNIX issue. You've got something non-standard going on there.

Comment: The server is running on a Media Template (dv) base which uses Virtuozzo for virtualisation.

Comment: Try searching the Virtuozzo message boards and bug tracking system and, perhaps, looking for upgrades to the Virtuozzo subsystem itself.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
(status,output) = commands.getstatusoutput("ps aux")
```

I thought this had fixed the exact same problem for me.
But then my process ended up getting killed instead of failing to spawn, which is even worse..

After some testing I found that this only occurred on older versions of python: it happens with 2.6.5 but not with 2.7.2

My search had led me here [python-close_fds-issue](http://bramp.net/blog/python-close_fds-issue), but unsetting closed_fds had not solved the issue. It is still well worth a read.

I found that python was leaking file descriptors by just keeping an eye on it:

```
watch "ls /proc/$PYTHONPID/fd | wc -l"
```

Like you, I do want to capture the command's output, and I do want to avoid OOM errors... but it looks like the only way is for people to use a less buggy version of Python. Not ideal...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simply

```py
$ sudo bash -c "echo vm.overcommit_memory=1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

It works for my case.

Reference: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/110#issuecomment-220672405

Answer (score 0):

> munmap(0xb7d28000, 4096)                = 0
>   write(2, "OSError", 7)                  = 7

I've seen sloppy code that looks like this:

```
serrno = errno;
some_Syscall(...)
if (serrno != errno)
/* sound alarm: CATROSTOPHIC ERROR !!! */
```

You should check to see if this is what is happening in the
python code.  Errno is only valid if the proceeding system call
failed.

Edited to add:

You don't say how long this process lives.  Possible consumers of memory

- forked processes
- unused data structures
- shared libraries
- memory mapped files

Comment: Yes, but we see from the OP's strace that the first syscall failure -- from clone() -- is ENOMEM as is reported.  This error is preserved along python's low-memory stumble through traceback construction, even though the C-library `errno` is reset many times along the way.