# Python Popen and communicate result in OSError related to memory allocation?

Tags: python, memory-management, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, subprocess

I am submitting jobs to a queue on a cluster and want to check if the job is done. The way I do it is to see if the `jobID` is present in the output of a command (called `jobs`) that lists all the jobs that are currently running. I call `jobs` via the shell, parse its output and see if `jobID` is there. If it isn't, that's interpreted as a signal that the job terminated:

```
   sleep = 2
   while True:
        output = subprocess.Popen("jobs %i" %(jobID),
                                  shell=True,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
        if job_done(output):
           break
        time.sleep(sleep)
```

Since `sleep` is set to 2, it means that this is checked every two seconds, but the job might run for several hours. I find that randomly I sometimes get the `OSError` `Cannot allocate memory`, even though there's a ton of memory on the machine and the thread does nothing that is memory intensive except check for the output of `jobs`. What could be causing this? Is there a better way to do this than to use `Popen`, `PIPE` and `communicate`?

This issue seems similar to the one reported here ([Python subprocess.Popen "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367373/python-subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory)) but there was no resolution to this issue.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) suggest that communicate might very well run out of memory in a scenario like yours

Comment: there are several solutions in the link that you've provided e.g., use a fork server.

Answer (score 0):

Which python version are you using? 2.6 or 2.7? or even newer? What's the status of your file-descriptors? See [fd-issue](http://bramp.net/blog/2010/05/python-close_fds-issue/).

At the bottom of the SO-post you mentioned there seems to be another one on the same issue. See also his [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263866/1107807).

Comment: I am using python 2.6.5. I read the post you linked to but I am not using `close_dfs=True` which that post said was the cause of the problem. Should I be using it? Even though I am using `PIPE`?

Comment: try a strace: `strace -o syscalls.trace -ttT ./yourscript.py` or for a shorter summary `strace strace -o syscalls.trace -Cf ./yourscript.py` In the eyes of python and the os, a PIPE is a file-like object which consumes a fd

Comment: what should I be looking for in `strace`?

Comment: for starters, just at the first odd-behaviour and errors. Either the firs EMEM or EBADF errors should be a help in the right direction.

Comment: But is this the correct way safe-proof way to check if a process has a particular output, periodically, in Python? Is there a different solution?

Comment: strace traces systemcalls, that's way it seem to me like the right choice if my hunch with the fd is correct. alternativly, did you look into celery?