# Jenkins and django: "Cannot allocate memory" with popen from django-jenkins run

Tags: python, django, jenkins, popen, django-jenkins

I'm using jenkins to run my django tests, with [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins)

since a few days (without changing confs), when i run django-jenkins i get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

even if my tests pass.

the complete error (from jenkins) is here https://gist.github.com/apelliciari/5106439

In my test i have some LiveServerTestCase with Selenium.

Searching for the error, i've found these

[Python subprocess.Popen "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367373/python-subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory)

http://bramp.net/blog/2010/05/python-close_fds-issue/

Hope they are useful, unfortunately my knowledge of python/unix is not so deep, and i can't grok how to fix it.

Is there a way to run tests avoiding the forks? I don't care if they take more time.

Comment: Having the same issue with django-jenkins running Django's test suite. Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Do your tests take longer than with the default test runner? I am noticing significant delays too in certain test cases.

Comment: sorry i didn't found a solution. i've dropped jenkins :( and i've passed to nose (with django-nose) for the tests.