# python subprocess OSError 12 Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a program written in python (version 2.7.4) which has 3 threads.

One thread is processing some data and does some web service requests ,
the other (MONITOR THREAD) inserts the data in a database and the other is responsible to 
open a monitor a vpn connection.

In order to do that it uses the openvpn client (ubuntu linux).
It does that by invoking

```
subprocess.Popen(openvpn_cmd)
```

the above command does a fork, as I understood, each time is executed.

This command is executed every hour. After 3-4 executions the following exception occurs:

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: related: [Python subprocess.Popen “OSError: \[Errno 12\] Cannot allocate memory”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1367373/4279)

Comment: to workaround the issue, you could try to run `subprocess.Popen` loop from within a child process `multiprocessing.Process` instead of a thread. Start the child process before starting threads or allocating memory, other resources in the parent process.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian This did the trick.