# Theano: Cannot allocate memory error for "shape.eval()" but not "np.asarray"

Tags: python, theano

When I try to print the shape of a shared variable using shape.eval(), I get a "Cannot allocate memory" error.  But when I convert it to a numpy array (thereby moving it to CPU), I can not only get the shape but also the array itself.  See below where it is stopped in pdb, data has been loaded into CPU/RAM and then I am trying to print the shape of p1:

```
(Pdb) p1
W
(Pdb) type(p1)
<class 'theano.sandbox.cuda.var.CudaNdarraySharedVariable'>
(Pdb) p1.shape.eval()
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
/usr/bin/g++ -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o /home/ubuntu/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.13--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty-x86_64-2.7.6-64/tmpe2w2zz/990b9feb030f7691b8412ea91249349d.so /home/ubuntu/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.13--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty-x86_64-2.7.6-64/tmpe2w2zz/mod.cpp -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7
ERROR (theano.gof.cmodule): [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
2015-08-20 12:09:19,032 theano.gof.cmodule cmodule.py:1083 ERROR [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
*** OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
(Pdb) a1 = np.asarray(p1.eval())
(Pdb) a1.shape
(21504, 2048)
(Pdb) a1
array([[ 0.03940072, -0.03306604, -0.00602638, ..., -0.00931167,
         0.05510775,  0.02733043],
       [snip]
       ...,
       [-0.06175347,  0.03134078, -0.06079643, ..., -0.03223133,
         0.00347659,  0.03415193]], dtype=float32)
```

borrow is set to True for p1, but this should not matter since I am using GPU, right?

There is enough free space in memory:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15039      14815        224          0          1       4112
-/+ buffers/cache:      10701       4338
Swap:            0          0          0
```

This error is a RAM (as opposed to GPU memory) error, right?  Why am I able to print the shape after getting the variable to CPU (using np.asarray), but shape.eval() prints an error?

What's a good way to address this issue (besides, may be, getting more RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329386/650654).

`eval()` invokes `subprocess()` (for compiling) which in turn invokes `fork()`.

This process had a very large amount of virtual memory (`vsize`) allocated to it.  Also, there was no swap configured on this host.  Even though the actual memory needed to execute this `eval()` would have been tiny, I believe the `fork` failed in allocating virtual memory and hence the error.

Adding swap space made the issue go away.  The swap space never got used, but I believe was sufficient to satisfy the virtual memory allocation.