# Getting OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory while scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl data.While crawling data after a short period memory error occurs.
 `OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`
What could be the reason for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess.Popen "OSError: \[Errno 12\] Cannot allocate memory"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367373/python-subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory)

Answer (score 0):

This may be occuring because you are running out of memory. Try into increase swap memory using the following commands.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1024k
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Then open fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then add the following line to make the swap change permanent.

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Reference [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Could you show us your spider please. It's possible that restructuring your soider will use less memory. For example, if you read an entire csv file at the start of the scrape that could chew up a lot of memory. Or queuing a lot of `Request`s at the start of the run.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify also how many memory to use on the scrapy project `settings.py` file:

```
MEMUSAGE_ENABLED = True
MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB = 1024
```

I think scrapy uses `512` as default memory usage.