# runtime: failed to create new OS thread with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I'm running 7 docker containers on an Ubuntu machine.

When I start all the containers, they run fine. However, after a while, two of them stop running (even though I ran the `docker run` command with the `--restart always` option).

Then, I inspected these two containers (using the `docker inspect` command) and saw that the following error was thrown:
`runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 7 already; errno=11)`

I also counted the number of threads that are running in the docker process (20), using the command `ps huH p <PID> | wc -l`.

I suppose I can't have so many containers running at the same time, right?

What should I do to avoid this system overload?

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting out of memory or other limits:

- [runtime: failed to create new OS thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557801/runtime-failed-to-create-new-os-thread)
- [golang runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2049 already; errno=12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484627/golang-runtime-failed-to-create-new-os-thread-have-2049-already-errno-12)
- And, as possible solutions: [Python subprocess.Popen "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367373/python-subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory/13329386#13329386)
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/runtime-may-need-to-increase-max-user-processes-ulimit-u/22055