# How to extract domains from the anywhere in the text file?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import re

with open('text.txt', 'r') as fh:
     re.findall(r'^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]+\.){1,}[a-z0-9]+\Z"',fh.readline())
print(p)
```

I am trying to extract the domains or url from this file:  [File link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95SWN3TDZMRTlvTGc/view?usp=sharing)
I would like to know how I can do that using regex method.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: are there linebreaks between lines?

Comment: Yes each on one single line. And I am trying to extract all the domains from the file. It may happen that one line have 2 domains so need to extract them. Please can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of the mentioned file is looked very much like JSON encoded dictionary.
So it's a good case for `json` module:

```
import json

with open("text.txt", "r") as fh:
    domains = []
    for l in fh.readlines():
        d = json.loads(l)
        domains.append(d["name"])
        # some url domains are located in `value` key for the records which have "type":"cname" 
        if (d["type"] == "cname"): domains.append(d["value"])

print(domains)
```

The output:

```
['mail.callfieldcompanion.com', 'reseauocoz.cluster007.ovh.net', 'cluster007.ovh.net', 'ghs.googlehosted.com', 'googlehosted.l.googleusercontent.com', 'isutility.web9.hubspot.com', 'a1049.b.akamai.net', 'plato.mx25.net']
```

---

If the input file contains a single line use the following approach:

```
import json, re

with open("text.txt", "r") as fh:
    domains = []
    # emulating the list of dictionaries
    line = "[" + re.sub(r'\}\s*\{', '},{',fh.read()) + "]"
    l = json.loads(line)
    for d in l:
        domains.append(d["name"])
        # some url domains are located in `value` key for the records which have "type":"cname"
        if (d["type"] == "cname"): domains.append(d["value"])

print(domains)
```

Comment: Let me try this my friend.

Comment: I got this error`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    d = json.loads(l)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 98 (char 97)
`

Comment: @JafferWilson, remember my question *are there linebreaks between lines?* ? According to your answer *Yes each on one single line.* I assumed that each line is on separate line. It will work if each line ended with linebreak. (maybe, it was misunderstanding)

Comment: Oops... I have checked my file and found tat they are not seperated with newline... I am deeply sorry for that. I checked it last time and thought they are seperated but not seems to.. Is there anything we can do?

Comment: I used your first approach and it gave me, this error now: `OSError: [Errno 12] Not enough space`

Comment: that error, I suppose, doesn't correlate with parsing such small text file. See this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216794/python-subprocess-popen-erroring-with-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory Also, have you tried the second approach?

Comment: Yes I did... :) Thank you. But what if the problem is related to large files is this not solution appropriate for larger files?

Comment: If I could receive such a big file, I would test it in both cases

Comment: Actually what I got is beyond sharing capacity. 200+ gB... :(

Comment: ok I tried something like this.. I hope this works: https://justpaste.it/14vtc  What you say?

Comment: If we avoid using the `readlines` then the program works fine.